# Connection via cloud identify-Aware Proxy failed Code 1006

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, cloud

When I use the jupyter notebook from GCP, During the running process, it will have no activity in SSH. However according to the previous post, if the SSH has been inactivity for 1 hour, it will disconnect and result with an error code of 1006.
Is there a way to keep SSH activity or other ways to avoid this error of inactivation?
[image: 1]

Comment: Your session is timing out. To keep your session active, you need to be active in the session.

Comment: @JohnHanley so what is the solution when this happens? The only way I could find was to restart the instance which is not ideal.

Comment: I am not aware of a solution. If you are not using the service, you will be disconnected.